# Sitecore SXA is displaying body-top place holder on all pages

Tags: sxa

Our solution is currently on Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.8 , until yesterday all our deployments were working as expected. All of a sudden, I am facing the Mythical Body-top placeholder problem - http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/mythical-sxa-body-top-placeholder

1. I have tried adding a new Theme
2. Re-serializing my theme as mentioned in the blog post
3. Compared the Configs
4. Compared HMTL on SXALayout.cshtml

The same build deployed on a Higher environment is working as expected

Has anyone here faced a similar problem, any suggestions to resolve it?

Update:

As suggested in the comments , i have deleted the Optimize-min items from all themes , there are no javascript errors on the console

[image]

Comment: Do you have a custom theme there? Are there any console errors? Typically, when there is a custom script in the custom theme which is causing problems (console errors) the logic which is hiding those placeholders is not triggered. Check that... I would also check if the problem will be gone when you will remove all optimize-min items from all themes (your custom one and all SXA base themes).

Comment: @DawidRutkowski , thanks for you reply , yes we have a custom theme , there are no console errors (please check the image attached in Question) , i have also deleted all optimize-min items from all the themes , unfortunately the problme still persists  , is there anything else i can check ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have also custom layout not only custom theme that you have created.

Create this patch file and insert your layout ID (in this format `{BCFC7537-EFF4-434C-96F5-BF4F55FD175B}` - This is ID of default SXA MVC Layout) where I put placeholder text ($Insert_Your_Layout_ID_here$):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <experienceAccelerator>
      <mvc>
        <!-- List of placeholders which should be hidden. -->
        <hiddenPlaceholders>
          <layout id="$Insert_Your_Layout_ID_here$">
            <placeholder name="head"/>
            <placeholder name="body-bottom"/>
            <placeholder name="body-top"/>
          </layout>
        </hiddenPlaceholders>
      </mvc>
    </experienceAccelerator>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Afterwards body-top placeholder should be hidden.